Usage of Async Context managers and Async Iterators in Async library in Python
When we use Async context managers and iterators in Python, I don't see any value in them. Because in context manager, when aenter() and aexit() are called into, they become the only tasks made available in the event loop. And similarly when using Async iterators, the anext() is going to be the only task in the event loop.
Basically when we have more than one tasks available in the event loop, then asyncio provides us the CPU advantage. When one task is blocked due I/O or N/W operation, the other task if it is ready, can hold the CPU.
But in the case of Async context managers and iterators, the event loop always tend to have a single task.
Any advantageous use case of utilising them?

What if file you're accessing is in cloud, or in VM? should entire program stall for few hundred milliseconds? How about establishing simultaneous connections while guranteeing it to do asynchronous graceful exit? There could be many async context managers running parallel in every connections or every IO streams prepared to do Graceful Asynchronous Exit for you, so you don't have to write try-except await ~~.aclose() every code! I'll write some examples when I'm home for ya!

Imagine this:

You want to asynchronously connect to server
You want to asynchronously get data from sever
You want to asynchronously gracefully exit


This would look like this without async context managers.
import aiohttp

async def read_without_context_mgr(url: str) -> str:
    """Checks if HTTP requests are available."""

    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    try:
        # need to wrap each with block with try-except because
        # name it's using could be None, giving AttributeError on finally.

        resp = await session.get(url)
        try:
            return await resp.text()
        finally:
            await resp.release()

    finally:
        await session.close()


With async context manager, it will look much cleaner and readable. Also convey strong meaning to user that

"Our manager handles all, you just use it and forget about cleanup"

with use of with keyword.
import aiohttp

async def read_with_context_mgr(url: str) -> str:
    """Checks if HTTP requests are available."""

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()


Do we need concurrency or not?
However, some would argue that:

That can be done with Non-Async Context Manager, since there's only one task running!

Then, I should ask back - WHY use Concurrency when it's not needed at the first place.
If there's only one task going to run anyway, then Asynchronous operations Adds Overheads and is Slower than synchronous operations.
If only one task is expected to be running, you Don't need Concurrency, you need this:
import httpx

def read(url: str) -> str:
    """Synchronously read data and guarantee graceful disconnection"""
    resp = httpx.get(url)
    try:
        return resp.read().decode()
    finally:
        resp.close()



Asyncio and IO
Whole idea of Concurrency is to allow asyncio to do DO IO CONCURRENTYLY - not to free some CPU or else.
To understand why, we need to understand IO. (Network is also IO btw)

IO Operations are like this in thread's perspective:

"Hey OS, please do this IO works for me. Wake me up when it's done."
Thread 1 goes to sleep
Some time later, OS punches Thread 1
"Your IO Operation is done, take this and get back to work!"

Yes, like 99.9% time what Thread 1 was doing during IO work is Doing Nothing. This is similar with what happens with time.sleep(). Thread does nothing meanwhile!
To quote from David Beazley (slide 106):

asyncio uses OS's IO Notification interfaces to do this. By sleeping until OS punch the main thread up that new event has arrived. Which means, our program literally doesn't run in CPU while waiting for OS awakes it (if I understand correctly)
With this, asyncio can push off blocking IOs to OS (or thread if it's not asyncio native, i.e. some 3rd party that implements asyncio via asyncio.to_thread)
Hence, is why asyncio is ASYNC + IO. It does IO Asynchronously by utilizing threads that will instead do the 'lazily doing nothing' part instead of main thread.


Example 1 - Slow HDD, Network drives
Finally coming back to __aexit__ and __aenter__ - now you'll understand how it's useful. By running bunch more of those!
Imagine some Slow harddrive that stopped spinning to save power - we need to wait at worst few seconds until it fully spins up, just open a file. Or, file itself could be in network far away, mounted as virtual drive.
In such case - letting other task to do their thing while we wait for that file to open, sounds like a better idea. In that way we could even wait for dozens more files at same time, virtually increasing throughput of IO operation by doing nothing!
class AsyncFileIOManager:
    async def __aenter__(self, path):
        ...
        return await self.file.wait_open(path)


    async def __aexit__(self):
        ...
        await self.file.wait_close(path)

Refer trio.Path which implement such asynchronous file IO.


Example 2 - Slow Network and protocol
Same goes for network (as that's also IO) - since we are waiting for NIC (Network Interface Controller) anyway, we can do other useful thing meanwhile!
class AsyncNetIOManager:
    async def __aenter__(self, path):
        ...
        return await self.connection.wait_open(path)


    async def __aexit__(self):
        ...
        return await self.connection.wait_close(path)


Or perhaps, you want to implement bit of protocol after connection to make sure we're communicating with right opponent!
client.py:
"""
Demonstration of AsyncContextManager usage for network
"""

import asyncio
import logging
import itertools
from typing import Union


logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)


SERVERS = (
    ("127.0.0.1", 9001),
    ("127.0.0.1", 9002),
    ("127.0.0.1", 9003),
)

# really, really, bad way to check matching protocol
HANDSHAKE_SEND_PHRASE = "Do you love me?".encode()
HANDSHAKE_RECV_PHRASE = "I can really move!".encode()


class AsyncSocketClient:
    uid_gen = itertools.count()

    def __init__(self, url: str, port):
        self.url = url
        self.port = port
        self.uid = next(self.uid_gen)

        self._reader: Union[asyncio.StreamReader, None] = None
        self._writer: Union[asyncio.StreamWriter, None] = None

    async def _connect_n_validate(self):
        """Connect and validate opponent. Raises AssertionError on protocol mismatch."""

        logger.info(f"[{self.uid}] Connecting to {self.url}:{self.port}")
        self._reader, self._writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.url, self.port)

        logger.info(f"[{self.uid}] Connected! Sending credential")
        self._writer.write(HANDSHAKE_SEND_PHRASE)
        await self._writer.drain()

        logger.info(f"[{self.uid}] Awaiting server response")
        assert HANDSHAKE_RECV_PHRASE == await self._reader.read(1024), "Protocol mismatch"

        logger.info(f"[{self.uid}] Connection validated!")

        # send anything as ack
        self._writer.write(" ".encode())
        await self._writer.drain()

        logger.info(f"[{self.uid}] Handshake done!")

    async def _ensure_connection_close(self):
        """Closes & wait for send buffer to be drained,
        and finally connection's terminated"""

        logger.info(f"[{self.uid}] Closing connection to {self.url}:{self.port}")
        self._writer.close()
        await self._writer.wait_closed()

    async def __aenter__(self) -> asyncio.StreamReader:
        try:
            await self._connect_n_validate()
        except AssertionError:
            # Oops, dialed wrong home. close active connection then rethrow
            if self._writer:
                await self._ensure_connection_close()

            raise
        return self._reader

    async def __aexit__(self, _exc_type, _exc_val, _exc_tb):
        await self._ensure_connection_close()


async def some_io_task(url: str, port: int):
    """Establish 'secure' connection and receive some data"""

    async with AsyncSocketClient(url, port) as reader:
        _ = await reader.read(1024)
        logger.info(f"Receive done from {url}:{port}")


async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(some_io_task(url, port)) for url, port in SERVERS
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


server.py:
"""
Serverside code
"""

import asyncio


HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORTS = [9001, 9002, 9003]


# really, really, bad way to check matching protocol
HANDSHAKE_RECV_PHRASE = "Do you love me?".encode()
HANDSHAKE_SEND_PHRASE = "I can really move!".encode()


async def callback(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    print("Connected")

    # if not valid close and return
    if HANDSHAKE_RECV_PHRASE != await reader.read(1024):
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()

    try:
        # valid, send our phrase
        writer.write(HANDSHAKE_SEND_PHRASE)
        await writer.drain()

        # wait for any write as ack
        await reader.read(1024)

        # now send some data
        writer.write("Sorasaki hina".encode())
        await writer.drain()

    # close
    finally:
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()


async def main():
    servers = [
        await asyncio.start_server(callback, HOST, port) for port in PORTS
    ]

    for server in servers:
        await server.start_serving()
        print(server)

    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(10000)
    finally:
        await asyncio.gather(*servers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

client output:
2024-04-30 02:23:45,528 - [0] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9001
2024-04-30 02:23:45,529 - [1] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9002
2024-04-30 02:23:45,529 - [2] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9003
2024-04-30 02:23:45,530 - [0] Connected! Sending credential
2024-04-30 02:23:45,530 - [0] Awaiting server response
2024-04-30 02:23:45,530 - [1] Connected! Sending credential
2024-04-30 02:23:45,530 - [1] Awaiting server response
2024-04-30 02:23:45,530 - [2] Connected! Sending credential
2024-04-30 02:23:45,530 - [2] Awaiting server response
2024-04-30 02:23:45,531 - [0] Connection validated!
2024-04-30 02:23:45,531 - [0] Handshake done!
2024-04-30 02:23:45,531 - [1] Connection validated!
2024-04-30 02:23:45,531 - [1] Handshake done!
2024-04-30 02:23:45,531 - [2] Connection validated!
2024-04-30 02:23:45,531 - [2] Handshake done!
2024-04-30 02:23:45,532 - Receive done from 127.0.0.1:9001
2024-04-30 02:23:45,532 - [0] Closing connection to 127.0.0.1:9001
2024-04-30 02:23:45,532 - Receive done from 127.0.0.1:9002
2024-04-30 02:23:45,532 - [1] Closing connection to 127.0.0.1:9002
2024-04-30 02:23:45,532 - Receive done from 127.0.0.1:9003
2024-04-30 02:23:45,532 - [2] Closing connection to 127.0.0.1:9003

Here, we see multiple protocol checks at __aenter__ are happening concurrently!


Example 3 - Task Groups, or Nursery
Those are all IO levels, but same can also be achieved in Task level, by awaiting all the tasks within the scope at __aexit__.
Such are widely utilized in many async libraries to provide pool-like user interface while freeing users from the annoying responsibilities.
Another usage would be TaskGroup that
recently got added to asyncio.
TaskGroup is an attempt to implement Structured Concurrency in asyncio, by creating a scope that allow safe task spawn/cancellation control to improve asyncio's stability. This also utilizes __aexit__ to achieve such safe exit behavior.
async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        task1 = tg.create_task(some_coro(...))
        task2 = tg.create_task(another_coro(...))
    print(f"Both tasks have completed now: {task1.result()}, {task2.result()}")

Such idea and move was motived by Nathaniel J. Smith, who wrote really informational post about asyncio's limitaion from it being a callback-soup, and designing an alternative structure.
And is also an author of library which implemented it years ahead, ground-up pure structured concurrency library trio.
import trio
import random


async def io_task(task_id, duration: float):
    print(f"[Task {task_id}] Started at {trio.current_time()}")
    await trio.sleep(duration)
    print(f"[Task {task_id}] Ended at {trio.current_time()}")


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        # unlike asyncio, one can only spawn task inside nursery
        for task_id in range(5):
            nursery.start_soon(io_task, task_id, random.uniform(1, 4))
    
        # nursery automatically waits for ALL spawned tasks to end,
        # thanks to __aexit__ waiting for all child tasks to finish


if __name__ == '__main__':
    trio.run(main)

[Task 0] Started at 187889.49744924367
[Task 1] Started at 187889.51567944366
[Task 2] Started at 187889.51607384367
[Task 3] Started at 187889.51625884365
[Task 4] Started at 187889.51640644367
[Task 4] Ended at 187890.84462484368
[Task 1] Ended at 187892.20549374365
[Task 2] Ended at 187892.67550124368
[Task 0] Ended at 187893.04400814365
[Task 3] Ended at 187893.48095184367

Which, I highly recommend you to try out how stable & intuitive it is!
Salute those who read until the end, all these are eventually necessary to understand, believe me.

Hi jupiterbjy, thank you very much for the detailed explanation and your invaluable time to draft this explanation!! At the moment, I am going through this.. I would take some time for me to digest this info.

@user3103957 no problemo! I also scratched my head for weeks trying to understand concept behind asyncio when I was studying back in army. Fluent Python written by Luciano Ramalho tries it's best explaining it so also check it out if you still find this confusing!

sure, thanks for all your effort!! I truly appreciate it.

@user3103957 guess my explanation didn't cut well I see, lemme know what to suppliment.

no, yours is really good. sure, I will let you know if I need anymore. Thanks for checking!! I really appreciate your time.

@user3103957 there was major issue on explanation at section Asyncio and IO, updated accordingly - TL;DR it doesn't spawn threads implicitly but main thread literally sleeps until IO notification is sent from OS it seems. sorry!
